# What is the convergence rate of the iterative optimization method?

Tags: convex-optimization, global-optimization

For the following optimization problem:
$$
\mathrm{min}_{A,B} \|I-A^{T}XB\|^2 + \lambda\|B\|^2,
$$
where $A$ and $B$ are the two variables ($\|A\|^2 \le \rho$ where $\rho$ is a constant, e.g. 1), the [paper of He](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7115188) uses a method that iteratively computing A and B to solve it.

Here is the method:

Denote the objective function by $\phi$.

STEP 1:
Suppose $A$ is given. By requiring the gradient of
$\phi$ respect to B vanish, we have
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial B}=0 \rightarrow B=(X^TAA^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TA.
$$

STEP 2:
Suppose $B$ is given. By requiring the gradient of
$\phi$ respect to A vanish, we have
$$
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial A}=0 \rightarrow A=(XBB^TX)^{-1}XB.
$$
Let $\|A\|^2 \le \rho$ by deviding by a constant.

Thus by iteratively executing STEP 1 and STEP 2 until convergence, we can solve the optimization problem.

The question is what the rate of convergence?

Comment: This is an instance of block coordinate descent.

Comment: This problem is definitely not convex. But the step 1 and step 2 problems in which one of A or B is fixed are convex.

Comment: @Dirk wrote "This is an instance of block coordinate descent". Well, maybe of something called block coordinate descent, except I don't think this algorithm necessarily even descends, i.e., false advertising..

Comment: This is all very strange. Consider $1\times 1$ matrices (a.k.a. numbers) with $x=\lambda=1$. You want to minimize $(1-ab)^2+b^2$ but it is the classical example of a polynomial whose infimum is $0$ but is not attained, so what "rate of convergence" are we talking about? In general, multiply $A$ by a huge number and divide $B$ by the same number to get a better pair from any given pair.

Comment: @fedja Thanks for your insightful comment. I miss a  constrain in the variable $A$. And I have corrected it and fixed the description of the solution.

Comment: @Mark L. Stone thanks for your helpful comments. This problem is not convex, I have fixed the description.

Comment: What is the basis for your claim that iteratively executing STEP 1 and STEP 2 results in convergence to anything, let alone to a global, or even local, minimum of your problem? Your algorithm does not employ any safeguards, such as line search or trust region, in order to guarantee convergence to a stationary point from an arbitrary starting point. Perhaps that is addressed in the paper, but I don't have access to it. Analysis of rate of convergence is premature until convergence has been established.

Comment: The $A$ update as written now is outright ridiculous. It does not diminish the value of the functional in general. Check once more that you haven't misunderstood anything in the paper. The scheme, as you presented it now, *does* converge but to something that has very little to do with the minimizer.

Comment: @fedja Thanks for your helpful comments. Yes, the method mentioned above seems to lack some significant proof to ensure it finally converges to the minimum. You mentioned that it does converge. If we don't care about the position of convergence, we only care about the rate of convergence,  can you give me some advice?

Comment: @MarkL.Stone  Thanks for your helpful comments. I agree with you but cannot find the answer in the original paper. If I only care about the rate of convergence, but not care about where it converges to, can you give me some advice?

Comment: What is the rate of convergence defined to be when it doesn't converge? My suggestion is to worry first about whether it converges, and to the solution,, not only in idealized theory, but in practice, with all the vagaries of finite precision floating point computation. Many papers are rather cavalier about this. Very few algorithms in published papers, even in top tier journals, actually work worth a damn in practice. If you want to make this algorithm reliable and robust, use a line search or trust region, which are absent from your description.

Comment: I guess you can talk about rate of convergence to the wrong answer. That's like an airline or railroad bragging that we now get you quicker to the wrong place.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone Thanks. I guess maybe converge to the "wrong answer" also makes sense, since we can easily determine the solution is whether a local minimum or local maximum.

Comment: The answer might be neither kocal min or local max. Could be a saddle point. or maybe even something else?

Comment: @Mark L.Stone The original paper hasn't discussed that the answer is a local min or local max, or even a saddle point. I think all three types of points are possible.